# Split text but include pattern in the first splitted part

Tags: python, regex

Looks very obvious but couldn't find anything similar. I want to split some text and want the pattern of the split condition to be part of the first split part.

```
some_text = "Hi there. It's a nice weather. Have a great day."

pattern = re.compile(r'\.')

splitted_text = pattern.split(some_text)
```

returns:
`['Hi there', " It's a nice weather", ' Have a great day', '']`

What I want is that it returns:

`['Hi there.', " It's a nice weather.", ' Have a great day.']`

*btw: I am only interested in the re solution and not some nltk library what is doing it with other methods.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on the whitespace with a lookbehind to account for the period. Additionally, to account for the possibility of no whitespace, a lookahead can be used:

```
import re
some_text = "Hi there. It's a nice weather. Have a great day.It is a beautify day."
result = re.split('(?<=\.)\s|\.(?=[A-Z])', some_text)
```

Output:

```
['Hi there.', "It's a nice weather.", 'Have a great day', 'It is a beautify day.']
```

`re` explanation:

`(?<=\.)` => position lookbehind, a `.` must be matched for the next sequence to be matched.

`\s` => matches whitespace ().

`|` => Conditional that will attempt to match either the expression to its left or its right, depending on what side matches first.

`\.` => matches a period

`(?=[A-Z])` matches the latter period if the next character is a capital letter.

Comment: What if there is a typo like no whitespaces in between like: "Hi there.It's a nice weather.Have a great day."

Comment: Very nice solution! Could you elaborate on the re part. Having a hard time understanding it exactly. Actually this part:  \.(?=[A-Z])

Comment: @Geveze The lookhead and lookbehind provide a matching requirement that must be met for the actual provided expression to match. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Note that this solution is incorrect when there is no space in between the sentences. Notice the missing `.` in `'Have a great day'`. The requirement of the question is to include the `.` in the results.

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler and more efficient to use `re.findall` instead of splitting in this case:

```
re.findall(r'[^.]*\.', some_text)
```

This returns:

```
['Hi there.', " It's a nice weather.", ' Have a great day.']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use capture groups with `re.split`:

```
>>> re.split(r'([^.]+\.)', some_text)
['', 'Hi there.', '', " It's a nice weather.", '', ' Have a great day.', '']
```

If you want to also strip the leading spaces from the second two sentences, you can have `\s*` outside the capture group:

```
>>> re.split(r'([^.]+\.)\s*', some_text)
['', 'Hi there.', '', "It's a nice weather.", '', 'Have a great day.', '']
```

Or, (with Python 3.7+ or with the [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)) use a zero width lookbehind that will split immediately after a `.`:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\.)', some_text)
['Hi there.', " It's a nice weather.", ' Have a great day.', '']
```

That will split the same even if there is no space after the `.`.

And you can filter the `''` fields to remove the blank results from splitting:

```
>>> [field for field in re.split(r'([^.]+\.)', some_text) if field]
['Hi there.', " It's a nice weather.", ' Have a great day.']
```

Comment: Note that a zero-width pattern is not allowed in `re.split` until Python 3.7.

Answer (score -1):

If each sentence always ends with a `.`, it would be simpler and more efficient to use the `str.split` method instead of using any regular expression at all:

```
[s + '.' for s in some_text.split('.') if s]
```

This returns:

```
['Hi there.', " It's a nice weather.", ' Have a great day.']
```